# In Laravel is there a way to add values to a request array?

Tags: php, laravel

I come across a situation in Laravel while calling a store() or update() method with Request parameter to add some additional value to the request before calling Eloquent functions is there any way for that.

```
function store(Request $request) 
{
  // some additional logic or checking
  User::create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: What type of treatment do you want to make? Do you want to add key values to `$request->all()` array?

Comment: Yes I need to add a Key value

Comment: Can't you use the `array_add()` helper? `$array = array_add($request->all(), 'new_key', $value);`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-array-add If this is not the kind of thing you are looking for, could you provide more information for your question?

Comment: $request is php object, as my understand, if you want to add some features in side the controller, convert the request object in to an array then add what ever you want

Answer (score 311, accepted):

Usually, you do not want to add anything to a Request object, it's better to use collection and [`put()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-put) helper:

```
function store(Request $request) 
{
    // some additional logic or checking
    User::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['index' => 'value']));
}
```

Or you could [union arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

```
User::create($request->all() + ['index' => 'value']);
```

But, if you really want to add something to a Request object, do this:

```
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']); //add request
```

Comment: Yes it is working for me now  I have changed the code as  function store(Request $request) 
{
  // some additional logic or checking
  $plan = 123; // some logic to decide user's plan
  $request->request->add(['plan' => $plan]);
  User::create($request->all());
}

Comment: This doesn't work because $request->all() is an array not a collection.

Comment: I guess it must be
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);

Comment: $request->request->add ... I got the error message 「Undefined variable: request 」 But I had the 「use Illuminate\Http\Request;」why I got the error message?

Comment: Does I need to $request=collect(); first?  Is $resquest a collection or array?

Comment: The union example is backwards if you want index to be overwritten

Comment: @alexey Can you please add why is it not a good idea to add stuff to Request?

Comment: Not working in Laravel 9:
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);

This works:
$request->merge(["key"=>"value"]);

Comment: This was not in the Laravel 9 upgrade guide either

Answer (score 101):

I tried `$request->merge($array)` function in Laravel 5.2 and it is working perfectly.

Example:

```
$request->merge(["key"=>"value"]);
```

Comment: This should be marked as valid answer. Works in Laravel 9.

This no longer works in Laravel 9:
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);

Comment: yes @JohnSmith is right. I have the same issue with $request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']); in Laravel 9. I dont know why they dont mention this in Upgrade documentation.

Answer (score 70):

Referring to `Alexey Mezenin` answer:

While using his answer, I had to add something directly to the Request Object and used:

```
$request->request->add(['variable', 'value']);
```

Using this it adds two variables :

```
$request[0] = 'variable', $request[1] = 'value'
```

If you are a newbie like me and you needed an associate array the correct way to do is

```
$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);
```

Hope I saved your some time

PS: Thank you `@Alexey`, you really helped me out with your answer

Comment: $request->request->add ... I got the error message  「Undefined variable: request  」 But  I had the   「use Illuminate\Http\Request;」why I got the error message?

Comment: @robspin I think its quite late, but you probably did not inject the request in the function
Eg: function (Request $request)

Comment: For those of you who are looking for why your value is not inserting in database as I didn't declared that value of database in my `Model` Class as: `protected $fillable = ['slug'];`

Answer (score 32):

enough said on this subject but i couldn't resist to add my own answer. I believe the simplest approach is

```
request()->merge([ 'foo' => 'bar' ]);
```

Answer (score 23):

You can also use below code

`$request->request->set(key, value).`

Fits better for me.

Comment: At least with Laravel 5.6 this is how it's done! Great answer

Answer (score 19):

In laravel 5.6 we can pass parameters between Middlewares for example:

FirstMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$params)
{
    //some code
    return $next($request->merge(['key' => 'value']));
}
```

SecondMiddleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$params)
{
    //some code
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: That `$request->merge()` method FTW! Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

simply use this:-

```
$request->merge(['index' => 'value']);
```

**work for me**

This will add a new value to your request object with the given index and use can use it in your function or while saving all request data into the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55782530/1191147).

Answer (score 9):

**Based on my observations**:

`$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);` will (mostly) work in *POST, PUT & DELETE* methods, because there is value(s) passed, one of those is `_token`. Like example below.

```
<form action="{{ route('process', $id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
</form>

public function process(Request $request, $id){
    $request->request->add(['id' => $id]);
}
```

But [below code] won't work because there is no value(s) passed, it doesn't really add.

```
<a href='{{ route('process', $id) }}'>PROCESS</a>

public function process(Request $request, $id){
    $request->request->add(['id' => $id]);
}
```

---

When using *GET* method you can either declare *Request* and assign value(s) on it directly. Like below:

```
public function process($id){
    $request = new Request(['id' => $id]);
}
```

Or you can use `merge`. This is better actually than `$request->request->add(['variable' => 'value']);` because can *initialize*, and *add* request values that will work for all methods (*GET*, *POST*, *PUT*, *DELETE*)

```
public function process(Request $request, $id){
    $request->merge(['id' => $id]);
}
```

**Tag:** laravel5.8.11

Answer (score 5):

you can use laravel helper and **request() magic method** ...

```
request()->request->add(['variable1'=>'value1','variable2'=>'value2']);
```

if you are using **api** route or use in console **command** ,you can use **query**  instead of **request** like this:

```
 request()->query->add(['variable1'=>'value1','variable2'=>'value2']);
```

Answer (score 4):

To add a new parameter for ex: `newParam` to the current `Request` Object, you can do:

```
$newParam = "paramvalue";
$request->request->add(['newParam' => $newParam]);
```

After adding the new parameter, you would be able to see this newly added parameter to the Request object by:

```
dd($request);//prints the contents of the Request object
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this code to add something to my request.

```
$req->query->add(['key'=>'variable']);
$req->request->add(['key'=>'variable']);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best one I have used and researched on it is `$request->merge([])` (Check My Piece of Code):

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    not_permissions_redirect(have_premission(2));
    $filters = (!empty($request->all())) ? true : false;
    $request->merge(['type' => 'admin']);
    $users = $this->service->getAllUsers($request->all());
    $roles = $this->roles->getAllAdminRoles();
    return view('users.list', compact(['users', 'roles', 'filters']));
}
```

Check line # 3 inside the index function.

Answer (score 2):

You can access directly the request array with `$request['key'] = 'value'`;

Answer (score 2):

You can add parameters to the request from a middleware by doing:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->route()->setParameter('foo', 'bar');
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add a query param to the Request object that can be obtained by calling

```
$request->get('key')
```

OR

```
$request->all()
```

The following works well for me.

```
$request->query->set('key','value');
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
RawPlot::create($req->all() + ['user_id'=>$user_id]);
```

This is a simple method to merge new variables into the request.

Answer (score -2):

You can also do `$request['key'] = 'value';` on newer Laravel versions.