# Laravel: Is there a way to reuse a method that is using a Request variable as parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, request

I want to reuse my method `store` that is in `generar\productoController`

`public function store(Request $request){}`

and I want to reuse it in this class `adquisicion\ComprasController`, I know that I have to import the class to use the method i want, but the problem is the $request variable, should I create a new object of it with `$request = new Request()`, adding the data I want with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107903/laravel-is-there-a-way-to-add-values-to-a-request-array) and sending it as parameter?

Thx for the help I'm really new with laravel

Comment: You could extract the reusable parts in a helper function that both controller functions can use ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try it like this  `$this->store(request(),$otherData)`
use the helper to get the current object of request

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Request` data to other method

```
productoController(Request $request){
     // anything here
    return redirect('your route name')->with('data', $request->all());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two ways that can make methods reusable in laravel application:

1. **Make a helper method**

   Create a `Helpers` folder in `app` folder, and create all static methods inside a `helper.php`

   **Helper.php**

   ```
   namespace App\Helpers;

   class Helper {

       public static function store() {
           $request = request();
           // ....
       }

   }
   ```

   **YourController.php**

   ```
   namespace App\Repositories;

   use App\Helpers\Helper;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class YourController extends Controller
   {

       public function store(Request $request) {
           // call the store method as
           Helper::store();
       }

   }
   ```

   The downside here is you will mix up all the non-related helper methods here and may difficult to organize.
2. **Repository**

   You can use a [Repository Pattern](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/) to architect your application, for example, if you store a `foo` object to your datastore, then you can first create `Repositories` folder in `app` folder, and create `FooRepository.php` in `Repositories` folder:

   **FooRepository.php**

   ```
   namespace App\Repositories;

   class FooRepository {

       public function store() {
           $request = request();
           // ... 
       }

   }
   ```

   **YourController.php**

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use App\Repositories\FooRepository;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   class YourController extends Controller
   {
       private $fooRepository = null;

       public function __construct(FooRepository $fooRepository) {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->fooRepository = $fooRepository;
       }

       public function store(Request $request) {
           // call the method as
           $this->fooRepository->store();
       }

   }
   ```