# How to insert a static field in request array (Laravel 5.7)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am having an issue with some small feature of a store function, and it seems that I didn't find any proper answer on the internet that will work for me.

I want to add static data in the array request, so that when sent data the field checked in the pivot table will be automatically filled with some integer.

I have the following tables:

```
Schema::create('mounter_evaluations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('project_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->text('mentions')->nullable();
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});  

Schema::create('mounter_procedures', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('mounter_norm_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->string('detail');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('mounter_procedures_checks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('mounter_evaluation_id')->unsinged()->nullable()->index();
    $table->integer('mounter_procedure_id')->unsinged()->nullable()->index();
    $table->integer('checked')->unsinged()->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The following models:

```
public function mounterevaluation() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\MounterEvaluation',
        'mounter_procedures_checks',
        'mounter_evaluation_id',
        'mounter_procedure_id'
    )->withPivot(['checked']);
}

public function mounterprocedures() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\MounterProcedures',
        'mounter_procedures_checks',
        'mounter_evaluation_id',
        'mounter_procedure_id'
    )->withPivot(['checked']);
}
```

Here is my store function:

```
public function store(Request $request, $idProiect) {
    $evaluation = MounterEvaluation::where('project_id', $idProiect)->first();
    if (!$evaluation) {
        $evaluation = new MounterEvaluation();
        $evaluation->project_id = $idProiect;
    }
    $evaluation->mentions = $request->mentions;
    $evaluation->save();

    // $request->request->add(['checked' => 1]);
    // $evaluation->mounterprocedures()->sync($request->procedures);

    // $evaluation->mounterprocedures()->sync($request->all() + ['checked' => 1]);
    $evaluation->mounterprocedures()->sync($request->procedures);
    // $request->request->add(['checked' => 1]);
    $evaluation->mounterprocedures()->request->add(['checked' => 1]);
    return response()->json($evaluation, 201);
}
```

Every time a person checks some filed in the evaluation form, this check is to be stored in the pivot table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel is there a way to add values to a request array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107903/laravel-is-there-a-way-to-add-values-to-a-request-array)

Comment: try this $request->merge(["key"=>"value"]);

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `$request` array the simple way as you put values in any other array like so:

```
$request['new_key1'] = 'new value 1';
$request['new_key2'] = 'new value 2';
```

Here is how I know it works for sure, in your controller you have Request instance, passed as parameter and then you can add values normally like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function example(Request $request)
{
     $request['new_key1'] = 'new value 1';
     $request['new_key2'] = 'new value 2';
     dd($request->input('new_key1'));//new value 1
}
```

In your case, if `$request->procedures` is an array then you could do:

```
$request->procedures = $request->procedures->toArray();
$request->procedures['checked'] = 1;
$evaluation->mounterprocedures()->sync($request->procedures);
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Hi,
 
Thank you for your response. But unfortunately, this didn't work for me :(
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

        // $request['checked'] = 0;
        // $evaluation->$request['checked'] = 0;
        $request->request->add(['checked' => 0]); //add request

Still didn't work.

Indirect modification of overloaded property

Comment: Edited the answer, try again

Comment: Thank you again for your help!

But weird enough I still get this error...

Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::$procedures has no effect

Comment: It's ok w will figure it out, updated the answer, try it with `$request->procedures = $request->procedures->toArray();` line in front, and let me know what error you get

Comment: Thank you for your time! When I tried like this I got the error: Call to a member function toArray() on array
 I've removed the array and It worked. but the thing it didn't work how it supposed to. The field checked remained null and the checked value moved to the mounter_procedure_id from the table.

In the json I am feeding in postman I am using it like this:
link: /mounterevaluation/1
mentions => 'something'
procedures => '2'

Comment: I will need a sample of `$request->procedures`, exactly what does it have inside it so that I understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I am using this procedures like this:    procedures[] =>2 and for every field, I want to check I must send procedures[] with the respective number.

Comment: `procedures[] =>2` ? that doesnt make sense and where is 'checked' key inside the procedure array? I meant to give an example of how `procedures` array look like