# Laravel Validator Not Returning Key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a new API call for our project.

We have a table with different locales. Ex:

```
ID  Code
1   fr_CA
2   en_CA
```

However, when we are calling the API to create Invoices, we do not want to send the id but the code.

Here's a sample of the object we are sending:

```
{
   "locale_code": "fr_CA",
   "billing_first_name": "David",
   "billing_last_name": "Etc"
}
```

In our controller, we are modifying the `locale_code` to `locale_id` using a function with an extension of `FormRequest`:

```
   // This function is our method in the controller
public function createInvoice(InvoiceCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->convertLocaleCodeToLocaleId()->validated();
}

// this function is part of ApiRequest which extend FormRequest
// InvoiceCreateRequest extend ApiRequest
// So it goes FormRequest -> ApiRequest -> InvoiceCreateRequest
public function convertLocaleCodeToLocaleId()
    {
        if(!$this->has('locale_code'))
            return $this;

        $localeCode = $this->input('locale_code');

        if(empty($localeCode))
            return $this['locale_id'] = NULL;
        
        $locale = Locale::where(Locale::REFERENCE_COLUMN, $localeCode)->firstOrFail();

        $this['locale_id'] = $locale['locale_id'];

        return $this;
    }
```

If we do a dump of `$this->input('locale_id')` inside the function, it return the proper ID (1). However, when it goes through `validated();`, it doesn't return `locale_id` even if it's part of the rules:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'locale_id' => 'sometimes'
        ];
    }
```

I also tried the function merge, add, set, etc and nothing work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be. The request is already validated by the time you get to your `...->validated();` line in the controller, why mess with validation a 2nd time?  Just optionally [add the field to the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107903/laravel-is-there-a-way-to-add-values-to-a-request-array) at that point.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It need to be part of the request so when it happen internally, we don't need to add it everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormRequest` will run before it ever gets to the controller. So trying to do this in the controller is not going to work.

The way you can do this is to use the [prepareForValidation()](https://laravel.com/docs/validation#preparing-input-for-validation) method in the `FormRequest` class.

```php
// InvoiceCreateRequest

protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    // logic here

    $this->merge([
        'locale_id' => $localeId,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seem to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad I could help. You could mark it as accepted so I can get some points :)

Comment: You got it ! :)