# Laravel - Trait in a Model with Specific Parameter

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to provide; multi tenancy in single database.

What I want to do is;
I want to create a new tenant, that will force model to add extra parameter in every "get" method.

And actually, i want to do the same for "create" method also.

Whenever user wants to get some data from specific model,
i want to add extra "where" inside it automatically like;

```
where('tenant_id', auth()->user()->tenant_id);
```

or for create methods

```
tenant_id => auth()->user()->tenant_id
```

how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52047497/7644018) might be what you need?

Comment: Consider taking a look at something like https://tenancyforlaravel.com/, which will do this automatically for you. There's a lot of complexity lying in such things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global scopes or local scopes

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#query-
scopes

For example, you can act like this

global scopes

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class PublishedScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model): void
    {
        $builder->where(['status' => 1]);
    }
}
```

In your article model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new PublishedScope);
    }

    //etc
}
```

Or using local scopes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function scopePublished(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->where(['status' => 1]);
    }

    //etc
}
```